# Why figure wrapping isn't part of the mainstream latex?

Tags: wrapfigure

Wrapping a figure seems to me like a basic feature that is prevalent enough. Why isn't it added to the mainstream latex?

This feature seems to involve enough complexity such that a mere package cannot handle adequately. Issues for example:

1. Two floating wrapfigures in a row:
   [Two floating wrapfigures in a row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/559704/two-floating-wrapfigures-in-a-row?noredirect=1#comment1411721_559704)
2. Incorrect figure numbering using wrapfigure:
   [Incorrect figure numbering using wrapfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495900/incorrect-figure-numbering-using-wrapfigure)
   , which sounds like an issue that old latex compilers had (with figures), which was resolved at the time with `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}`.

Comment: I feel your pain, but *why*-type questions are generally off-topic for this site as they mostly tend to invite speculation and argumentation by anecdote. Moreover, your posting very much sounds like a feature request, which again is off-topic for this site. You may want to (re-)post your query/request to https://www.latex-project.org/bugs/.

Comment: Your point 2 is wrong, as explained in the accepted answer in the post that you link to, why do you reference fixltx2e (and the issue and the answer are still the same as they were then)

Comment: Can we have 'wrapping figures is *hard* to the point of being impossible on a global basis'?

Comment: it is not at all surprising that wrapping is in a package. Most document level things are, latex doesn't define a `figure` environment or `\section` command either, they are defined in class files such as `article`.

Comment: Mico, they don't support external packages. I'm not sure about features. David, I added clarification to the second point that I was referring to figures. Good point, I'll try to email Boris that maintains acmart.cls.

Comment: Wrapping a single paragraph around an image is fairly easy.  Trying to wrap multiple paragraphs and non-standard text is more difficult.  Worst case, you can use minipages and \nopar (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513895/wrap-text-around-tikzpicture-environment/514000?r=SearchResults&s=3|28.2927#514000).

Comment: John, I have a problem with "manually break it" (if I understand it correctly). My main issue is that I don't want to play around with the wrapped figure each time my document is changed. Latex is supposed to avail me from that.